# Finding ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_7$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am having difficulty of finding the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ . My preliminary attempt is that (d) is an ideal iff d is a divisor of 7. Hence, the ideals I currently have are (1) and (7). Is this correct?

Comment: As $7$ is prime, $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is a field. Thus, the only ideals are $\{[0]\}=\langle[7]\rangle$ and $\mathbb{Z}_7=\langle[1]\rangle$.

Comment: $(d)$ is always an ideal.

Comment: $\langle 2\rangle$ is also an ideal and $2$ is not a divisor of $7$. Can you guess which of the two ideals it is?